# How do I make a word frequncy counter case sensitive using command line interface in Perl?

Tags: bash, script, perl

So I have this Perl Script which is a word frequency counter. But now I have to modify this script and make it case sensitive. So if a user adds -i on the command line, the script should compare in a case-sensitive way.
If the -i is not entered on the command line, it should compare in the old case-sensitive way.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#words hash
my %words;

while( my $a = <> )
{
    chomp $a;
    foreach my $word ( split ( /\s+/, $a ))
    {
        $words{$word}++;
    }
}

foreach $word (keys %words)
{
    print "<$word> appears $words{$word} times\n";
}
```

Comment: You'll want to[`use Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) to help you with your option parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [`use Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) to help you with your option parsing, and set `$case_insensitive` to 1 if `-i` is given.

And then

```
foreach my $word ( split ( /\s+/, $a ))
{
    if ($case_insensitive) 
    {
        $words{lc $word}++;
    }
    else
    {
        $words{$word}++;
    }
}
```

or, more tersely

```
foreach my $word ( split ( /\s+/, $a ))
{
    $words{$case_insensitive ? lc $word : $word}++;
}
```